# Sorting PayPal Date in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sorting, date

PayPal's Date format is "HH:MM:SS MON DD, YYYY PDT", e.g. "21:49:27 SEP 12, 2013 PDT". In inputting the information into MySQL I simply copies the column I am really not even concerned the hour, minutes, and second. Presently I have:

strSQL = SELECT ID_PayPal, first_name, last_name, item_number, results_amount, donation_amount, country_code,  STR_TO_DATE(MID(payment_date,12,10), '%m-%d-%Y') AS date_for_sort FROM PAYPAL ORDER BY date_for_sort DESC"

The result is:

```
 Jan 26, 2013
 Jan 07, 2013
 May 26, 2013
 Jan 30, 2013
 Feb 23, 2013
 Sep 07, 2013
 Jan 14, 2013
```

As you can see not want I want. Suggestions? Thanks. Rick

Comment: Great thought. I seemed it would work, but here are my results:Jan 02, 2014
Jan 26, 2014
Jan 01, 2014
Jan 24, 2014
Jan 29, 2014
Jan 13, 2014
Jan 21, 2014
Jan 25, 2014
Feb 10, 2014
Apr 04, 2014
Jan 23, 2014
Mar 28, 2014
Jan 03, 2014
Mar 23, 2014
Jan 25, 2014
Apr 15, 2014
Apr 07, 2014
Apr 20, 2014
Jan 03, 2014
Jan 28, 2014
Jan 18, 2014
May 02, 2014
May 14, 2014
Feb 09, 2014
Jan 14, 2014
Jan 01, 2014
Jan 04, 2014
May 12, 2014
Jan 20, 2014
Feb 02, 2014

Comment: Could you add your table structure and some actual sample data? If the date is stored as a string in the format you're showing, my answer below should give the correct answer as the sqlfiddle shows, but if you're not giving all the details on how it's stored it may not.

Comment: I'll delete my answer below since "it doesn't work" isn't enough of a description to figure out why your data doesn't look like my working sample data.

Answer (score 0):

By using the `STR_TO_DATE()` function, I am guessing that you have a `varchar` string (not a date formatted column) for the `payment_date` column in the database.

I do not like functions inside functions as it can get confusing and they sometimes don't work... or could be the order in which they process... which one of the two seems to be the case in your situation.

Thus I suggest a sub-query is what you really need, as in the 2nd example below.

**The bottom line is:** Your `STR_TO_Date(,'**%m**-%d-%Y')` is not working or formatting based on your result set, obvious as the desired **%m** is still showing **Jan**-day-year rather than **O1**-day-year. Perhaps its a matter of missing quotes somewhere near or in the  **'** Mid() **'** but who knows?) I cant test without a creating a table and data.....

**%M** is the full month (January, February....)

**%m** is the numeric month (01, 02, 03.....which is what you are trying to format).

**%b** for short month  (Jan, Feb...)

Like I stated functions inside functions are temperamental so this might work.

```
MID(STR_TO_DATE(payment_date,"%T %m-%d-%Y"),12,10)
(remove this and the next line from query) 
(Not tested: re-adjust the 12,10 desired results as needed)
```

If the above does not fix the issue, you could start from scratch and try a double sub-query nested in the outer query of all the other results you desire... such as

**Inner subqueries**

```
SELECT  STR_TO_DATE(D1, "%m-%d-%Y")
FROM(
SELECT MID(payment_date, 12,10) AS D1)
AS date_for_sort ORDER BY date_for_sort DESC;
```

I would leave out the ORDER BY... and play with that last as it may need to be in the outer query result set!"the above is nested as part of an outer query that Is NOT shown/coded in the example".

But, this example works and is a starting point!

Breaking down the query it would be the same as:

Outer Query------01-10-2017 (in sql date format)

Inner Query----- July 10 2017 (a string)

and the result would be

**08-10-2017**

A date format that you can ORDER BY as **date_for_sort** is generated as a date -(Pointing out again, you did specify **%m** rather than **%b**).

I don't have a data table to work and test with as to offer you a working correction, thus the above 2nd code is hopefully a hint or nudge in the right directions.

The fact is there is about 3 query-code-combo-ways I can think of to query and get your results, but I don't want to confuse anyone as this reply is a few years late. lol.

Hopefully the OP has a working model in the 4+ years of this late response. :-)

Hope this helps someone else though!

BobDCoder